# How do I mix custom and standard error messages in validations on one form field

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuelidate

I am a beginner with Vuelidate and just completed [the Easy Form Validation with Vuelidate video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BR6Vvjw3wQ) on YouTube. I followed the video carefully and everything seemed to go okay but I've run into a bit of trouble after trying to extend the concepts. I can't find a relevant insight in the Vuelidate docs.

I don't like the default message that appears when the confirm password doesn't match the first password supplied, so I want to provide my own custom message for it but the default messages are fine when the confirm password is not supplied at all or the confirm password is too short. I've written the code as follows and don't see an obvious mistake but when I actually test the code in the browser, I find that it ALWAYS gives me the custom message, even if the required or minLength validations are the ones that are failing. Why is that, and how must I write my code differently to work as intended?

```
        <p>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" 
        v-model="state.password.confirm"/>
        <span class="error" v-if="v$.password.confirm.$error">
            <span v-if="v$.password.confirm.required | v$.password.confirm.minLength">
                {{v$.password.confirm.$errors[0].$message}}
            </span>
            <span v-else>
                {{"Confirm password must match password on previous line"}}
            </span>
        </span>
    </p>
```

Is it the "or" (|) in the v-if that is the problem? I thought a vertical bar (for "or") or an ampersand (for "and") were allowable in Vue but I may be confusing it with another language. I've just searched for an example containing a vertical bar or ampersand without success; all the examples I found use a single condition but I'm not sure if that's to keep things simple or because v-if can't handle more than one condition.

I'm using Vue3 and VSCode as my IDE.

Comment: try with 2 of them  `||` [read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)

Comment: @Nikola - Good suggestion but it doesn't work correctly. It gives the "required" message when nothing is entered in the field but in all other cases it gives the *default* sameAs message. It looks like v-if will not work with more than one condition.

Comment: @Nikola - I stand corrected: apparently it *is* valid to have multiple conditions in a v-if when the conditions are joined by || or &&. At least that's a claim I saw elsewhere in stackoverflow by someone who seemed to know what he was talking about. I'll look at other issues now to see why my code doesn't work.

Comment: hey mate, yes you are right, you can use conditions in v-if, or you can create computed property and do all conditions there, return proper response and check it in v-if :)